# How to compare pandas DataFrame timestamps to .ics file dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, icalendar

I have a data frame containing a column of Timestamps:

```
    Timestamp   
0   2017-11-09 14:55:29 
1   2017-11-09 14:58:29 
2   2017-11-09 15:01:29
```

I also have this .ics file containing a holiday calendar, which I have downloaded to my drive (full calendar is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PanderMusubi/dutch-holidays/master/DutchHolidays.ics

A sample entry looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180712T151328Z
SUMMARY:Eerste Paasdag (Easter Sunday)
UID:20180712T151328Z-17127-0077-en@katana
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180401
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20180402
ATTACH:https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eerste_Paasdag
CATEGORIES:Public Holiday
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

I would like to create a binary column next to df.Timestamp called 'Holiday' showing a 1 if the Timestamp date corresponds to a date where CATEGORIES: Public Holiday. This question is somewhat similar, but I don't understand the json or walk parts: [parse dates with icalendar and compare to python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238835/parse-dates-with-icalendar-and-compare-to-python-datetime)

I've tried this so far, but I'm very new to this so it's probably quite wrong:

```
import icalendar
calendar = icalendar.Calendar.from_ical('/Users/dpezim/Desktop/Python/DutchHolidays.ics')

for i in df.Timestamp:
    for event in calendar.walk('VEVENT'):
        if event['DTSTART'].dt <= i <= event['DTEND'].dt:
            df = df.assign(Holiday=1)
        else: 
            df = df.assign(Holiday=0)
return df
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Content line could not be parsed into parts: '/Users/dpezim/Desktop/Python/DutchHolidays.ics': /Users/dpezim/Desktop/Python/DutchHolidays.ics
```

Comment: Please attach some code of what you have tried before

Comment: Updated with code, although I don't think I understand the down votes? I clearly stated I don't understand how to code this, and included all required info?

Answer (score 2):

This code reads the ics file from web address and extracts all the events from it. From the dataframe *df* the code traverses through all the values in *TimeLine* and checks for event dates in the events object. If any event date matches with the timeline the it checks for categories of the event and based on the category it sets value of holidayCheck list. At the end of the code the list has been assigned to the corresponding dataframe column.

Please let me know whether this helps. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
import datetime as dt
import ics

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PanderMusubi/dutch-holidays/master/DutchHolidays.ics'


icsFile = c = ics.Calendar(urlopen(url).read().decode('iso-8859-1'))
holidayCheck = []
events = icsFile.events

for _datetime in df.Timestamp:

    dfDate = int(_datetime.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

    check = False
    for event in events:
        eventDate = int(event.begin.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

        if dfDate == eventDate:
            categories = next(iter(event.categories))
            if categories == 'Public Holiday':
                holidayCheck.append(1)
            else:
                holidayCheck.append(0)
            check = True
            break
        else:
            check = False

    if check == False:
        holidayCheck.append(0)

df = df.assign(Holiday = holidayCheck)
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the last line df = df.assign(Holiday = holidayCheck) - ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: please check the length of both the dataframe _df_ and _holidayCheck_ list

Comment: The Dataframe is [125250,9] whereas the holidayCheck list is only len=1410. Not sure why it's not running through the entire df.Timstamp column?

Comment: There was some indentation error in the code. Corrected it. Please check.

Comment: Ok, got it running now thanks. However, I don't think it's working properly; for example, when I search for the Christmas Day Timestamps (12-25), the Holiday column reads 0.

Comment: Then please check the christmas day timestamps on ics file events and check for the categories mentioned in the events. This can be done by running the loop on the events object.